# Getting Spring simpMessagingTemplate to work with websocket

Tags: spring-boot, websocket

I have been trying to get simpMessagingTemplate to send to websocket in Spring but to no avail. From what I can see of related stackoverflow posts and other guides, I have provided the necessary configuration and mapping of paths.

My code is shown as below:

RestController (which I use to invoke sending of the message to the websocket):

```
@RestController
public class RestControllers {

    @Autowired
    private SimpMessagingTemplate template;

    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public String doTest() {

        Message m = new Message();
        m.setFrom("foo");
        m.setText("bar");
        template.convertAndSend("/app/chat/test-topic", m);

        return m.toString();

    }

}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class ChatController 
{
    @MessageMapping("/chat/{topic}")
    @SendTo("/topic/messages")
    public OutputMessage send(@DestinationVariable("topic") String topic,
                  Message message) throws Exception


    {
        System.out.println("THE MESSAGE WAS RECEIVED:" +  message.toString());
    return new OutputMessage(message.getFrom(), message.getText(), topic);
    }
}
```

Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer
{
    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config)
    {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) //?? alternative only?
    {
        registry.addEndpoint("/chat").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

Comment: Which error are you getting?